# Webpack 4 splitChunks and libraryTarget

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks

I have some entries: `app`, `vendor`, `polyfills`, `bootstrap` and output as library `['app', '[name]']` and libraryTarget `var`.

In the browser `app` variable contains:

```
{bootstrap: Module, polyfills: Module, vendor: Module, app: Module}
```

If I use `optimization.splitChunks` to move rxjs to `bootstrap` chunk `app` variable contains:

```
{polyfills: Module, vendor: Module, app: Module}
```

(without `bootstrap` chunk)

My config:

```
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: {
    name: 'bootstrap'
  },
  splitChunks: {
    minSize: 1,
    chunks: 'all',
    cacheGroups: {
        vendors: false,
        default: false,
        rxjs: {
          name: 'bootstrap',
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]rxjs[\\/]/
        }
    }
  }
}
```

How to move `rxjs` to `bootstrap` chunk not lose `app.bootstrap` variable value?

Answer (score 0):

1. `vendor`, `polyfills`, `bootstrap` can't be entrypoints. only app is real entry point.
2. you should not manage chunks with webpack "manually", let say you have real entry points app1 and app2 (because you app consists from two pages); then webpack will generate those files for you:

vendor.js vendor~app1.bundle.js app1.js - should be loaded on first page

vendor.js vendor~app2.bundle.js app2.js - should be loaded on second page